# Firebase toObject with generic type

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It's my first question on StackOverflow, so if I'm doing something wrong, please help me.

I've been working on an Android application using Kotlin and Firebase Firestore and I have a data class with a generic type **T** property on it.

Well, my problem is: I'm getting an error when I try to use the toObject method to parse the Firestore object to my POJO. The error message says to use GenericTypeIndicator, but it doesn't exist on Firestore SDK. I tried to install the Firebase Database SDK to import this interface, but it didn't work as well.

Here's my POJO class:

```
@Parcelize
data class Policy<T : Parcelable>(var id: String = "",
                              var type: String = "",
                              var paid: Boolean = false,
                              var price: Double = 0.0,
                              var uid: String = "",
                              var policy: T? = null) : Parcelable
```

Here's my repository method:

```
override fun getPolicies(uid: String): Single<List<Policy<T>>> =
    Single.create {emitter ->
        db.collection(POLICIES_COLLECTION)
                .whereEqualTo(FIELD_UID, uid)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    emitter.onSuccess(it.toObjects(Policy::class.java) as List<Policy<T>>)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    emitter.onError(it)
                }

    }
```

Anyone can help me to figure how to make it work?

Comment: How did you use the GenericTypeIndicator ? Can you please put your code for that?

Comment: Honestly, I tried to implement GenericTypeIndicator, but I can't. I think it only works with Firebase Realtime Database methods. 

Comment: Any solution for this? I am trying the same in Java...